# Twitter Color Emojis on Ubuntu 20.10

Tags: 20.10, emoji

I have been unable to get the Twitter Color Emojis to work on Ubuntu 20.10,
I installed https://github.com/eosrei/twemoji-color-font (fonts-twemoji-svginot) but it seems to only be displaying the [noncolored Emojis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O5eNN.png).

Thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The README file on that repo says:

> The font works in all operating systems, but will currently only show color emoji in Firefox, Thunderbird, Photoshop CC 2017, and Windows Edge V38.14393+. This is not a limitation of the font, but of the operating systems and applications. [Why doesn't it work on Chrome?](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=306078) Regular B&W outline emoji are included for backwards/fallback compatibility.

This is probably the reason why this is happening. Also, try installing it with the installer script (mentioned as manual method in the README):

```
wget https://github.com/eosrei/twemoji-color-font/releases/download/v13.0.1/TwitterColorEmoji-SVGinOT-Linux-13.0.1.tar.gz

tar zxf TwitterColorEmoji-SVGinOT-Linux-13.0.1.tar.gz

cd TwitterColorEmoji-SVGinOT-Linux-13.0.1

chmod +x install.sh

./install.sh
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, with the default emoji font, color emojis worked just fine everywhere, why is Twitter Color Emoji not able to do the same?

Comment: It's a limitation of the other apps (as mentioned in the README) and the OS.